# Checking if two items in a list are the same?

Tags: python, regex

My Objective:

> In a game of Lingo, there is a hidden word, five characters long. The 
>   object of the game is to find this word by guessing, and in return 
>   receive two kinds of clues: 1) the characters that are fully correct, 
>   with respect to identity as well as to position, and 2) the characters 
>   that are indeed present in the word, but which are placed in the wrong 
>   position. Write a program with which one can play Lingo. Use square 
>   brackets to mark characters correct in the sense of 1), and ordinary 
>   parentheses to mark characters correct in the sense of 2)

Current Code:

```
def lingo():
    import random
    words = ['pizza', 'motor', 'scary', 'motel', 'grill', 'steak', 'japan', 'prism', 'table']
    word = random.choice(words)
    print word
    while True:
        guess = raw_input("> ")
        guess = list(guess.lower())
        word = list(word)
        for x in guess:
            if x in word:
                if x == word[word.index(x)]:
                    guess[guess.index(x)] = "[" + x + "]"
                else:
                    guess[guess.index(x)] = "(" + x + ")"
        print guess

lingo()
```

As of now, if the words share a common letter, it puts the letter in square brackets, regardless of whether it shares the same pos or not.

Examples:

CORRECT:
- Word: `Table`
- My Guess: `Cater`
- OUTPUT: `C[a](t)(e)r`

INCORRECT: 
- Word: `Japan`
- My Guess: `Ajpan` (Notice the switch between the a and j, I did that on purpose).
- OUTPUT: `[A][j][p][a][n]` (Should Be `(a)(j)[p][a][n]`)

Comment: So can you give us some sample inputs, the outputs you expect, and the outputs you're getting? It helps to know what is wrong, and how, with examples.

Answer (score 6):

Your error is this line:

```
if x == word[word.index(x)]:
```

which is always true since `word[word.index(x)]` is the same thing as `x`. Try changing it to:

```
if x == word[guess.index(x)]:
```

Comment: `if guess.index(x) == word.index(x):` also fails for the same reason you put on my answer. The only correct way would be `word[guess.index(x)]` i suppose

Comment: @munircontractor You are right, removed it. Now our answers are exactly the same :)

Answer (score 3):

`if x == word[word.index(x)]:` should be `if x == word[guess.index(x)]:`

Comment: This will fail with repeated characters. For example, if the word is `motor` and your guess is correct (`motor`) it will still return `['[m]', '[o]', '[t]', '(o)', '[r]']`